# How do I return a cgImage as an ImageView using SwiftUI and Xcode for macOS/

Tags: xcode, macos, image, swiftui

I have data stored in a Data object as [UInt8] to be rendered as a grayscale 8-bit image.  I don't know how to get from a cgImage to an image View.  The code below at least compiles up to the lack of a return value but I'm not certain that it is correct.  What do I need to add to return the image as a view?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageView_2: View {
    var data: Data
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let width = 320
        let height = 240
        
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        
        let context = CGContext(data: data.castToCPointer(), width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)
        let imageRef = CGContext.makeImage(context!)
        let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: imageRef()!)
        let image = imageRep.cgImage

        return
          //  .resizable()
          //  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }  
    
}
```

The extension to Data:

```
extension Data {
    func castToCPointer<T>() -> T {
        return self.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nate, does this https://github.com/kasimok/76267548 answer your question? What is the original color space of the input data?

Comment: The data came from  a stream, UInt16, of data from one of our IR research cameras (somewhat similar to a FLIR) and had to be extracted from the stream (which is stored on disk).  I scaled the data so each pixel is now 8 bits - UInt8.  The color is grayscale.

Comment: OK, please take a look at the repo I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `castToCPointer` is undefined behavior and can definitely crash, particularly when optimizations are turned on. It is invalid to access the pointer from a Data outside of the `withUnsafeBytes` closure. Luckily, it's also unnecessary.

The image View in SwiftUI is [`Image`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image), and accepts a NSImage as an input.

I haven't tested it out, but this should do what you're looking for:

```
struct ImageView_2: View {
    var data: Data

    var body: some View {

        let width = 320
        let height = 240

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

        let provider = CGDataProvider(data: data as CFData)!

        let image = CGImage(width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bitsPerPixel: 8 * 1,
                            bytesPerRow: width,
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: [],
                            provider: provider,
                            decode: nil,
                            shouldInterpolate: false,
                            intent: .defaultIntent)!

        return Image(nsImage: NSImage(cgImage: image,
                                      size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))
    }
}
```

Note that the `!` usage here will crash if the data is in a bad format. You can fix that using [`if-let`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics#Optional-Binding) to check them for nil. In that case, though, you will still need to return a valid View.

Comment: I shall try this in the morning.  BTW I'm assuming that height and width are in pixels, is that correct? If so 'bytesPerRow: 8 * width' looks suspect.

Comment: Yeah; it was supposed to be `width`

Comment: `SwiftUI.Image` can also be constructed with a `CGImage` directly, which would avoid the extra `NSImage` wrapper: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(_:scale:orientation:label:)

Answer (score 0):

display CGImage to SwiftUI:

```
// this
Image(decorative: cgImage, scale: 3, orientation: .up)
// and decoration
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
```